# How to pass route parameter value to middleware definition for route?

Tags: php, laravel, litespeed

I'm applying [Litespeed cache](https://github.com/litespeedtech/lscache-laravel) on our website and I need to use parameter value from route when calling `lstag` middleware.

I've already tried using

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->parameter('slug');
Request->route()->paremeter('slug');
Request::route('route.name')->parameter('slug');
```

and everything else I could find on the Internet, but nothing was working. It just throwed error 
In web.php line 103:

> Call to a member function parameter() on null

My full code for route is

```php
Route::get('serialy/{slug}', 'SerialsController@show')->name('serials.show')->middleware('lstag:serial.' . Route::getCurrentRoute()->parameter('slug'));
```

I expect that I can use a value of parameter when calling a route middleware (**lstag**), but I can't find any way to do it. Is it even possible?

Comment: The routes are registered before the route is dispatched ... there is no route handled at the time the routes are registered (there is no current route) ... if you need the value of a parameter you need to get it in the middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by @lagbox, the above won't really be possible.

However, you can use the lstags middleware in the controller `__construct()` ( https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#controller-middleware ).

There you should have the information available that you need to build up your `X-LiteSpeed-Tag` header as you wish.

Comment: So I'm calling `$this->middleware('lstags:tag')` and it is working.